# Quicksort for Objective-C

Tags: sorting, objective-c

This is quite plain vanilla, but I'm hoping for Objective-C specific feedback. Also I'd be interested in what folks think about sorting in Objective-C vs. doing all sorting in C or C++ (and which?) even in an app.

```
- (NSMutableArray *) quickSort: (NSMutableArray *)toSort{

    for(NSNumber *arrayMember in toSort){
        if(![arrayMember respondsToSelector:@selector(doubleValue)]){
                NSLog(@"incorrect types in input array, returning nil");
                return nil;
            }
    }

    int intLength = toSort.count;
    if (intLength == 0){
        return toSort;
    }
    else if (intLength == 1){
        return toSort;
    }else if (intLength==2){
        if ([toSort[0] doubleValue] <= [toSort[1] doubleValue]) {
            return toSort;
    }else{
        NSNumber *temp = [toSort objectAtIndex:0];
        [toSort replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[toSort objectAtIndex:1]];
        [toSort replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:temp];
        return toSort;
        }
    }

    int r = arc4random_uniform(intLength);
    double pivot = [[toSort objectAtIndex:r] doubleValue];

    NSMutableArray *lowArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *highArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *equalArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i = 0; i < intLength; i++){
        double arrayMember = [[toSort objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
        if (arrayMember < pivot) {
            [lowArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:arrayMember]];
        }else if (arrayMember > pivot){
            [highArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:arrayMember]];
        }else{
            [equalArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:arrayMember]];
        }
    }

    NSMutableArray *returnLeft = [self quickSort:lowArray];
    NSMutableArray *returnRight = [self quickSort:highArray];

    NSMutableArray *returnArray = returnLeft;
    [returnArray addObjectsFromArray:equalArray];
    [returnArray addObjectsFromArray:returnRight];

    return returnArray;

}
```

This function is written to sort `NSNumbers` formed from doubles. Here's a sample call:

```
NSNumber *number3 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:92.3];
NSNumber *number1 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:2.3];
NSNumber *number2 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:4.3];
NSNumber *number5 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:5.3];
NSNumber *number4 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:-5.3];

NSMutableArray *toSort = @[number1, number2, number3, number4, number5];
NSMutableArray *sorted = [self quickSort:toSort];
NSLog(@"here's sorted array: %@", sorted);
```

Comment: If you are using a `NSMutableArray`, then why wouldn't you just use the built-in `- sortUsingComparator:` method?

Comment: @JS1 I don't entirely know why except I noticed a job listing where people had to do more CS-y type things, like sorts, in Objective C so I wanted to see if there was something special 'besides' the direct sort SDK. But maybe it doesn't make sense...

Comment: @JS1 The sorting algorithm that `sortUsingComparator:` uses is undocumented.  And it's implementation details are subject to change without notice.  It may or may not be a quick sort.  And while I'm no sorting expert, I believe that different sort algorithms are more efficient in different scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Xcode 4.5 (and Clang 3.3), you can use an [Objective-C literal](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) to access an item in an `NSMutableArray` rather than `[myArray objectAtIndex:index]`.

For example, if I had an `NSMutableArray` of `NSString`s, I could do this:

```
NSString *firstItem = myArray[0];
```

You can also use [`firstObject`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSArray/firstObject) as well, rather than `myArray[0]`, like this:

```
NSString *firstItem = [myArray firstObject];
```

---

The spacing around your braces is also odd as well. For example, I'd recommend that this:

```
    ...
}else{
    ...
}
```

Be expanded to something like this

```
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

---

This entire section:

```
if (intLength == 0){
    return toSort;
}
else if (intLength == 1){
    return toSort;
}else if (intLength==2){
    if (toSort[0] <= toSort[1]) {
        return toSort;
}else{
    NSNumber *temp = [toSort objectAtIndex:0];
    [toSort replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[toSort objectAtIndex:1]];
    [toSort replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:temp];
    return toSort;
    }
}
```

Can be simplified down to this. This does fix the strange indentation and whitespace issues as well.

```
if (intLength == 0 || intLength == 1) {
    return toSort;
}
else if (intLength == 2 && toSort[0] <= toSort[1]) {
    return toSort;
}
NSNumber *temp = [toSort objectAtIndex:0];
[toSort replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[toSort objectAtIndex:1]];
[toSort replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:temp];
return toSort;
```

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> - (NSMutableArray *) quickSort: (NSMutableArray *)toSort{
>     for(NSNumber *arrayMember in toSort){
>         if(![arrayMember respondsToSelector:@selector(doubleValue)]){
>                 NSLog(@"incorrect types in input array, returning nil");
>                 return nil;
>             }
>     }
>
>     /* stuff */
> }
> ```

There is a lot to comment on in just this part of your code, so that's where my focus will lie.

---

First of all, given that we're working with a mutable array, we should simply sort it in place--and we should make the method a category of `NSMutableArray` itself.

```
@interface NSMutableArray(QuickSort)

- (void)quickSort;

@end
```

So it can be used as such:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = /* array instantiation */

[myArray quickSort];
```

I'd make a similar category for the immutable `NSArray` class which returns the sorted array:

```
@interface NSArray(QuickSort)

- (NSArray *)quickSortedArray;

@end
```

And that'd be used as such:

```
NSArray *unsorted = /* array instantiation */

NSArray *sorted = [unsorted quickSortedArray];
```

This makes our method signature make more sense.  Of course, `NSMutableArray` is a subclass of `NSArray`, so we can always apply the `quickSortedArray` method to an `NSMutableArray` as well, while the first recommendation (the simple `quickSort` method) simply sorts it in place and returns nothing.

---

So, that cleans up our method signature.  It makes it nice, and closer to what we'd expect to see with normal Objective-C methods.

But we've got a bigger problem.

Without documenting it, your method only works for objects which responds to the `doubleValue` selector, and inexplicably returns `nil` if anything else exists in the method.

Moreover, it can only sort the array in a single direction: ascending.

Rather than the zero argument `quickSort` or `quickSortedArray` methods I recommended, what we actually need is to accept some argument that tells us by what logic to sort the array.

We need a `NSComparator` argument.  This is what `NSComparator` is:

```
typedef NSComparisonResult (^NSComparator)(id obj1, id obj2);
```

In plain English, `NSComparator` is a block which takes two arguments (of any object type) and returns an `NSComparisonResult` (which describes how these two objects should be sorted).

So we want our `quickSort` method to take one of these and use this for the logic to sort the array.  Let the caller specify how they should be sorted.

So, if as a caller of the `quickSort` method, I know my array contains only `NSNumber` objects, I can pass a comparator that treats the two inputs as strictly `NSNumber`, and it doesn't impact your implementation of the sorting logic.

Comment: As an addendum, I *highly* recommend writing an accurate unit test for your sorting algorithm now that you understand the problems that can result from coincidences...